# XML Syntax Error: Please check the XML request to see if it can be parsed USPS Tracking API

Tags: api, tracking, usps

I am working on USPS Tracking API, and trying to send JSON request. Below is the request and its throwing 

    80040B19
    XML Syntax Error: Please check the XML request to see if it can be parsed.
    USPSCOM::DoAuth

just checking if USPS tracking api supports JSON requests. Thanks in advance

```
{
"TrackFieldRequest":{
    "attributes": {
        "USERID":" ",
        "PASSWORD":" "
    },
   "TrackID": {
         "ID": "283728384394304"
      }
}
}
```

Comment: use this to check for a valid json: https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1):

The USPS Webtools API suite employs the XML language, not JSON. Webtools was introduced about 20 years ago and at that time XML was state-of-the-art.  There are other address verification engines that accept JSON requests, but most of them have a small charge. Webtools is free.